# Stop regex from capturing a series of consecutive letters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, python-re

I have a chunk of text that has following series of substrings scattered randomly throughout the text -

```
17 ABC 200.30-3(a)
12 ABC 200.30
3 ABC 102.171-102.999
43 ABC 831.7000-1
22 ABC 1.168(a)-1
21 ABC 1.167(a)-5T
20 ABC 97.III
8 ABC 852.237-75
4 ABC 852
3 ABC 217.C
0 ABC Chart 230
1 ABC chart 220
15 ABC Xa. CI
22 ABC xa. III
58 ABC 236.303-1
66 ABC 101.1333
33 ABC 325.1Expression
45 ABC 230.12Gamestop
```

My regex should get me this output ->

```
17 ABC 200.30-3(a)
12 ABC 200.30
3 ABC 102.171-102.999
43 ABC 831.7000-1
22 ABC 1.168(a)-1
21 ABC 1.167(a)-5T
21 ABC 1.167(a)-5AB
20 ABC 97.III
8 ABC 852.237-75
4 ABC 852
3 ABC 217.C
0 ABC Chart 230
1 ABC chart 220
15 ABC Xa. CI
22 ABC xa. III
58 ABC 236.303-1
66 ABC 101.1333

33 ABC 325.1
45 ABC 230.12
```

I have a working regex that gives me what I need for the most part -

```
\d{1,2}\s*C\.?F\.?R\.?\s*(Part|part|Ch\.|ch\.)?\s*(\d+|[MDCLXVI]+)([\.\(|\)\-a-zA-Z\d]+)?
```

But the regex fails for the last two use cases. It captures -

```
33 ABC 325.1Expression
45 ABC 230.12Gamestop
```

How do I make the regex to stop capturing text if it sees a series of consecutive letters and return a match until the last seen `digit`. In other words, I want to add a check, if consecutive letters exceed > 3 (flexible as per my convenience), return match until the last digit found.

Also "Chart" and "chart" are accepted set of `>3` consecutive letters. Anything other than these, should be caught.

If it helps, the consecutive letters are always followed after a number in most cases.

Update:
What if I get all the matches and pass them through another regex ?
I was able to cover another edge case I had by doing this -

```
text : 27 ABC 740.19b-4.-----------------------------------------I
desired match : 27 ABC 740.19b-4
regex used to achieve this : '.+?(?=\.--)'
```

I was think of using a variation of this to apply on the above strings I have difficulty with. But couldn't find a way.

Comment: aren't "AB" and "III" consecutive letters?

Comment: Yes you're correct. But I want to add a check, if consecutive letters exceed > 3 (flexible as per my convenience), return match until the last digit found.

Comment: "Chart" is four consecutive letters. please be more precise

Comment: "Chart" is part of the exception list. "Chart", "chart", "Xa", "xa" should be ignored for this check.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already more-or-less satisfied with your regex and just want to eliminate those two cases, here is a simple suggestion: Encapsulate the original regex in an atomic grouping `(?>...)` to prevent backtracking, then follow it by a negtive lookbehind for exactly four consecutive letters `(?<![A-Za-z]{4})`

Comment: It didn't help my case but I used the lookbehind for another edge-case I had. So thanks !!
What about I extract the strings as it is and pass them through another regex match ?
Updated question for more context.